# MouseDown / MouseLeftButtonDown events not firing, MouseUp is?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Here's my code:

```
    public AbilitiesController(Abilities page)
    {
        _page = page;
        page.ScrollBar.MouseLeftButtonDown += MouseDown;
        page.ScrollBar.MouseLeftButtonUp += MouseUp;
        page.ScrollBar.MouseLeave += MouseLeave;
        page.ScrollBar.MouseWheel += MouseWheel;
        page.ScrollBar.MouseMove += MouseMove;
    }

    private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        if (!_dragBound) return;
        var newPos = mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(_page);
        var dPos = newPos - _pos;
        _page.ScrollBar.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(dPos.X);
        _page.ScrollBar.ScrollToVerticalOffset(dPos.Y);
        _pos = newPos;
        Console.WriteLine("Moved");
    }

    private void MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs mouseWheelEventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MouseWheel");
    }

    private void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        _dragBound = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Left");
    }

    private void MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        _dragBound = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Mouse Up");
    }

    private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        _dragBound = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Click!");
    }
```

Page is a Page, Scrollbar is a Scrollview.

I know my logic for moving the scrollbar probably isn't correct yet, but we aren't even getting that far yet.

For some odd reason the MouseDown event isn't firing whether I bind it to MouseDown or MouseLeftButtonDown.

However oddly enough the *MouseUp* event works no problem.

Which seems really odd because normally if one is broken, the other is too...

Using latest version of Visual Studio 2017 in a WPF project.

Comment: according to this post, it's likely mouse down has been overriden by the ScrollBar class already.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813608/wpf-button-mouseleftbuttondown-doesnt-work-at-all

Comment: Tried binding to page.MouseDown and page.MouseUp, still the exact same problem.

Comment: what about throwing an override on it.  Just a guess but that would work if it's been overridden in some base class.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100027/wpf-canvas-swallowing-mousedownevent .... use Focusable="False" on your ScrollViewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try 'PreviewMouseDown' instead of 'MouseDown' and same for all the other non-working mouse events, as they may already be being handled by whatever the base class of your 'Abilities' class is.

Comment: Not working in Magento 2 - mouseup/mousedown event does not fire on fotorama gallery.